# How to find best match based on the wording within the same cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We need to discuss about the way to look based on the wording in the cell rather than just looking the exact match of the cell value.

I am working on G-Sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMxfhzsN_eAO5kZZcBv4Difq2ybVU29mh8s__8a5gSk/edit?usp=sharing), In this I need find the best match based on the word inside the cell rather than matching the exact word. we all know Our most of the basic Look up function like Vlookup, Hlookup, Xlookup or Index-match only support for Look the whole wording.

Then I used [Split function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to {"=SPLIT(E3," ")"}, Split all word in 2nd Table.
Then I wrote [formulas](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) Using LET, HSTACK, BYROW, TOROW , CHOOSEROWS and Other formula. Below is the formula
=LET(a,HSTACK($D$2:$D$5, BYROW(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(XMATCH($F$2:$H$5,SPLIT(A2," "))),0),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))),TOROW(CHOOSEROWS(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(a,INDEX(a,,2)<>0),2,1),,1),1)))
But I think I need to do some correction on this, because this not give the 100% accuracy.

Comment: **A4** Value `XYZ BCD` seems to be an equal match to both `ABC CAB BCD` and `Dog Monkey XYZ`. Whats the criteria for `ABC CAB BCD`(*54321*) to be picked as output instead of `Dog Monkey XYZ`?!

Comment: Need to give Priority from Top to bottoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(z_,split(Λ," "), Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(F2:F)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,
 reduce(,sequence(counta(z_)),lambda(x,y,x+if(iferror(search(index(z_,y),index(F2:F,c))),1,)))))),
 xlookup(max(1,Σ),Σ,E2:E,)))))
```

- *Incase of multiple `equal` matches; top match in `Data 02` column will be picked*

[image]